# Solr CSVResponseWriter set csv.mv.escape to none

Tags: solr

The CSV writing parameter for Solr `csv.mv.escape` defaults to `\`. I don't want the multi-valued fields to be escaped but can't find a way of doing it.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/default/select?
q=*:*
&wt=csv
&csv.header=true
&csv.mv.escape=\
```

To remove the default escaping I'm wanting to be able to do something like this

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/default/select?
q=*:*
&wt=csv
&csv.header=true
&csv.mv.escape=none
```

How can this be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as [I can see in the source](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/java/org/apache/solr/response/CSVResponseWriter.java#L220), the escape value is set when the CSVStrategy is created, and then only set to a different value if a different value is provided. So I don't think there's a way to make Solr skip the escape.

```
CSVStrategy mvStrategy = new CSVStrategy(strategy.getDelimiter(), CSVStrategy.ENCAPSULATOR_DISABLED, 
    CSVStrategy.COMMENTS_DISABLED, '\\', false, false, false, false, "\n");
```

My only, bad, hackish  suggestion is, if this only for one time task, to use a value that doesn't occur in the text as the escape value, then replace that value after retrieving the CSV structure.

Answer (score 0):

not sure why, but `&csv.mv.separator=|` works for me